# Mirror with DropNet in C#

Tags: c#, dropbox, mirror, dropnet

in C# I'm creating a client to update my dropbox files from local files. it's not a synchronization.
Dropbox files must be a copy of local files (if local file is update then I must update on dropbox. if dropbox file is update I must do nothing on local). 
Like "robocopy /mir".
Is it a way to do this ?
thks

Comment: I test DropNet Api. Apparently , there is no function of mirroring with this API. I will have to compare each local file with DropBox file. but what metadata must I check ?

Comment: In the documentation is a sample to [upload a file](http://dkdevelopment.net/what-im-doing/dropnet/): `var uploaded = _client.UploadFile("/", "test.txt", content); ` So at least this can get you started to upload. Now you need to find out which files are already uploaded. This may depend on your use case; unless you put more details and effort in your question it is not very likely that you will get a good answer.

Comment: sorry for my English...

Comment: I (try) to resume. I want use DropNet on Windows Service because my app must work on a server. Then my app must work in none interactive session (no user logged). Then dropbox client (in systray) will not installed on machine. A schedule task copy user files on a folder (backup) and my app must copy this files on dropbox space. then I would not copy all files on dropbox but just created and modified file. I must fond files no similar between my local storage and bropbox storage.